# mysql select columns using subqueries for different results

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to select different columns in a single mysql query.  I know this is easily done is sql, but how do you do this is MySQL?

```
SELECT
MyfirstResult = (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount < 0),
MySecondresult = (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount > 0)
```

That query is fine for SQL but how do I port the same functionality to MySQl

my result should be 1000|2000 in this case.  A single row with 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse your syntax a little.  The column alias name follows the calculated expression or subselect via `AS aliasname`.

```
SELECT
  (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount < 0) AS MyFirstResult,
  (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount > 0) AS MySecondResult
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same;

```
SELECT
    (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount < 0) MyfirstResult,
    (select sum(Counted * PartCost) FROM tblParts WHERE resultofcount > 0) MySecondresult;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14329/2).

You can also do it slightly simpler in MySQL;

```
SELECT sum(Counted * PartCost*(resultofcount < 0)) Myfirstresult,
       sum(Counted * PartCost*(resultofcount > 0)) MysecondResult 
FROM tblParts
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14329/5).

Comment: nice that this eliminates the subquery with the clever multiply-by-bool